Explicitly define group by which to dodge in ggplot2
I would like a plot like the following one

However, if I try to achieve this with position_dodge() the line layer not only doges by gender but also by the group subject.
library(ggplot2)
dat <- structure(list(subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("F", 
"M"), class = "factor"), age = c(8, 10, 12, 14, 8, 10, 12, 14, 
8, 10, 12, 14, 8, 10, 12, 14, 8, 10, 12, 14, 8, 10, 12, 14, 8, 
10, 12, 14, 8, 10, 12, 14), y = c(21, 20, 21.5, 23, 21, 21.5, 
24, 25.5, 20.5, 24, 24.5, 26, 23.5, 24.5, 25, 26.5, 26, 25, 29, 
31, 21.5, 22.5, 23, 26.5, 23, 22.5, 24, 27.5, 25.5, 27.5, 26.5, 
27)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dat, aes(x = age, y = y, color = gender)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = subject), position = position_dodge(width = 0.6))


I can achieve it with position_nudge, but this becomes a lot of handwork if I have more then two levels in the dodge factor.
ggplot(dat, aes(x = age, y = y, color = gender)) +
  geom_point(position = position_nudge(x = ifelse(dat$gender == "M", 0.1, -0.1), y = 0)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = subject),
            position = position_nudge(x = ifelse(dat$gender == "M", 0.1, -0.1), y = 0))

Is there a solution where I can specify the factor by which to dodge explicitly? i.e.
ggplot(dat, aes(x = age, y = y, color = gender)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.6, group = gender)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = subject),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.6, group = gender))

Thanks for your help.

Well, the group aes is the "factor" which determines how the position will dodge or stack or ... . But there are cases (mostly related to lines) where TBMK it is not possible to achieve the desired result using the group aes and position, i.e. you want to dodge (aka group) by gender and at the same group by subject to connect the lines.
Instead I would go for manual dodging by setting the x positions for the lines appropriately (similar to your position_nudge approach). To this end I first convert gender to a numeric then use scales::rescale to rescale to the range of c(-.5, .5) and finally account for the dodge width. Still some manual work but does not require to condition on the categories of gender and can in principle be generalized for more factor levels:
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

dwidth <- .6

ggplot(dat, aes(x = age, y = y, color = gender)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = dwidth)) +
  geom_line(aes(
    x = age + dwidth / 2 * scales::rescale(
      as.numeric(gender),
      to = c(-.5, .5)
    ),
    group = subject
  ))



Thanks! Interesting approach with scales::rescale(). Do you think it would make sense to implement the possibility to explicitly define the group for position_dodge()?

One small issue: the solution above only works for continuous variables in the x-axis. Is there also a solution which works for both, numeric and factor variables on the x-axis?

If the variable mapped on x is a factoror character then you have convert to a numeric too, e.g. you could check using x = factor(age) and then use x = as.numeric(factor(age)) + dwidth / 2 * ... in geom_line.

Concerning your first question. As I said, group already set the grouping for position_dodge. What you have in mind would require to have a second group aes. From my understanding of how ggplot2 works I would approach that by adapting geom_line, i.e. adding something like a groupline to set the group for doding and for the lines separately.
